# Detecting if computer is idle based on mouse and keyboard interactions

Tags: c++, linux

I'm am writing a piece of software in C++ that controls the keyboard backlight on my MacBook Pro which runs Arch Linux as main OS and Debian for funzies. The program runs as a daemon and is as of now able to turn the keyboard backlight on. Next step is to make it keep an eye on when the computer is idle (based on mouse and keyboard interactions) and when it has been idle for some time, turn off the backlight, and as soon an interaction with keyboard or mouse is registered, turn the backlight on again.

I have googled around, but I havent found anything I could get working to check when the last mouse and/or keyboard interaction was registered.

Any idea to how I can achieve this?
I believe there already exists such capabilities in some part of any Linux OS (maybe X?) so using this would be preferable instead of writing from scratch.

Regards,...

Comment: Wait, Chris Bucholz from cracked.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XScreensaver extension in the X server tracks keyboard and mouse idle time.  If you download the source code to [Psi](http://psi-im.org), their source tree has a file `idle_x11.cpp` that contains logic to query the idle time.  Use that as an example.

The basic idea is to use `XScreenSaverQueryInfo` to read the screen saver status info.

Comment: Thanks for this - seems to be the right thing to go with - a search on google shows that, that is was most recommends for this case. About the Psi source and idle_X11.cpp - I cant find the file. I just cloned their git repo, so I guess I am looking the right place. Can you tell me exactly where in the source it is?

Comment: @Chris Buchholz They've refactored the source code so `idle_x11.cpp` is now in the `libpsi` repository.  With a Psi git checkout, do `git submodule init` followed by `git submodule update`, and the file is in `src/libpsi/tools/idle`.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution independent of the X server, you could watch the device nodes for any mice and keyboards for events and use a timer.

The `/dev/input/event*` nodes provide a generic interface - you would have to watch any of them that correspond to a mouse or keyboard. You need the `evdev` kernel module for this to be available.

The `/dev/input/mice` node provides an interface that aggregates all mouse events. If you write the code for the `/dev/input/event*` nodes, though, you could just use that for the mice as well.

Keep in mind that some X-server drivers will grab their device node and block all other applications from getting events, so you may have to either change their options or use an X-based interface as well.

EDIT:

If you want to use the `/dev/input/event*` device nodes, the [`/usr/include/linux/input.h`](http://debomatic.debian.net/natty/natty/usr/include/linux/input.h) header file contains most of what you'd need to know about the programming interface. From my experience, it's quite straightforward and simple to use. It would be even more so in your case, since you do not really care about *what* key was pressed - just that one was.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have been looking in to your approach, and this might come in handy when I need to react on presses to the keyboard-backlight-up/down buttons.