# Linux - Detecting idleness

Tags: c++, linux, bash, input

I need to detect when a computer is idle for a certain time period. My definition of idleness is:

- No users logged in, either by remote methods or on the local machine
- X server inactivity, with no movement of mouse or key presses
- TTY keyboard inactivity (hopefully)

Since the majority of distros have now moved to `logind`, I should be able to use its DBUS interface to find out if users are logged in, and also to monitor logins/logouts. I have used `xautolock` to detect X idleness before, and I could continue using that, but `xscreensaver` is also available. Preferably however I want to move away from any specific dependencies like the screensaver due to different desktop environments using different components.

Ideally, I would also be able to base idleness on TTY keyboard inactivity, however this isn't my biggest concern. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4508730/1781709), I should be able to directly query the `/dev/input/*` interfaces, however I have no clue how to go about this.

My previous attempts at making such a monitor have used Bash, due to the ease of changing a plain text script file, howver I am happy using C++ in case more advanced methods are required to accomplish this.

Comment: This may be a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: the linux command "last" gives you an entry list of login time of all users. So that part is just parsing the file.

Comment: @Peter `last` does not let me monitor logins and logouts however, and besides, `logind` is pretty much standard now anyway. It's the other parts I'm more concerned about.

Comment: last gives you both login and logout times. It doesn't monitor logins but you only wanted to check the time between login and logout, right? So how is your definition of XServer - Inactivity?

Comment: @Peter I just updated the definition, hopefully it's a little clearer now

Comment: If you don't mind digging through someone else's code, check out how HTCondor does it (http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor).  I'm pretty sure it's written in C++.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely shell standpoint (since you tagged this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)), you can get really close to what you want.

```
#!/bin/sh

users_are_logged_in() {
  who |grep -q .
  return $?
}

x_is_blanked() {
  local DISPLAY=:0
  if xscreensaver-command -time |grep -q 'screen blanked'; then
    return 0  # we found a blanked xscreensaver: return true
  fi
  # no blanked xscreensaver.  Look for DPMS modes
  xset -q |awk '
    /DPMS is Enabled/ { dpms = 1 }    # DPMS is enabled
    /Monitor is On$/ { monitor = 1 }  # The monitor is on
    END { if(dpms && !monitor) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 } }'
  return $?  # true when DPMS is enabled and the monitor is not on
}

nobody_here() {
  ! users_are_logged_in && x_is_blanked
  return $?
}

if nobody_here; then
  sleep 2m
  if nobody_here; then

    # ...

  fi
fi
```

This assumes that a user can log in in two minutes and that otherwise, there is no TTY keyboard activity.

You should verify that the `who |grep` works on your system (i.e. no headers).  I had originally grepped for `/` but then it won't work on FreeBSD.  If `who` has headers, maybe try `[ $(who |grep -c .) -gt 1 ]` which will tell you that the number of lines that `who` outputs is more than one.

I share your worry about the screensaver part; xscreensaver likely isn't running in the login manager (any other form of X would involve a user logged in, which `who` would detect), e.g. GDM uses gnome-screensaver, whose syntax would be slightly different.  The DPMS part may be good enough, giving a far larger buffer for graphical logins than the two minutes for console login.

Using `return $?` in the last line of a function is redundant.  I used it to clarify that we're actually using the return value from the previous line.  `nobody_here` [short circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so if no users are logged in, there is no need to run the more expensive check for the status of X.

---

Side note:  Be careful about using the term ["idle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_%28CPU%29) as it more typically refers to resource (hardware, that is) consumption (e.g. CPU load).  See the `uptime` command for [load averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29) for the most common way of determining system (resource) idleness.  (This is why I named my function `nobody_here` instead of e.g. `is_idle`)